# Can `required` name be missing from `properties` in the OpenAPI schema

Tags: openapi

I am reading the [OpenAPI v3.1 specification](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0) and trying to find any info regarding the `required` field that can be defined for a media type for a request's body. From the examples it is clear that if `required` contains a name of an `properties` item, the item is required.

However, there are cases (I suppose), where `properties` field can be omitted for `type: object`, meaning that an `object` with arbitrary fields can be accepted.
I suppose that for a `type: object` where the `properties` field is not specified it is not allowed to specify a `required` list with names. But I can't find an excerpt that would **explicitly** state that it is not allowed.

Hence, the question:
**Is it allowed by an OpenAPI specification to mention a property name in `required` that is not mentioned in the `properties` or when the `properties` field is not defined?**

---

Example 1:

```
required: 
  - name
  - age
# not specified
# properties:
```

Example 2:

```
properties:
 - name
# `age` is missing from the properties
required:
 - name
 - age
```

---

##### UPDATE

According to [json-schema.org](https://json-schema.org/draft-04/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.5.4.3.2):

> An *object instance* is valid against this keyword if its property set contains all elements in this keyword's array value. [emphasis added]

Strictly speaking, it seems to be allowed...

Answer (score 1):

The specification itself isn't very restrictive, but if you use a linting or validation tool and there's a required property that isn't defined, I'd expect the tool to let you know there's a problem.

Comment: I have tried in https://apitools.dev/swagger-parser/online/ but it didn't yield any errors when `properties` don't contain the `required` field

Answer (score 1):

> Is it allowed by an OpenAPI specification to mention a property name in `required` that is not mentioned in the `properties` or when the `properties` field is not defined?

Yes. This behavior comes from JSON Schema, where each keyword is a standalone constraint that is evaluated separately from other constraints.

Basically, this schema:

```yaml
type: object
required:
  - foo
```

is equivalent to:

```yaml
type: object
required:
  - foo
properties:
  foo: {}   # or  foo: true  in OAS 3.1+
```

and means the property `foo` must be present, regardless of its value (i.e. it can have any value).

But as @Lorna noted, some API vendors and tooling vendors consider it a good practice to explicitly define all known properties in `properties`. So depending on the tools that you use, required properties that aren't explicitly defined may be flagged as warnings/errors, even if it's technically valid OpenAPI.

Comment: So it boils down to an agreement within the department...